# How can i assign static RtMidi callbacks object wise?

Tags: c++, function, static, callback, midi

i'm using the C++ RtMidi library to read MIDI input from two identical devices (Novation launchpad).
Both launchpads 'live' in their own object, open their own MIDI port and (should) have their own callback method set. However if i push buttons on the launchpads, both devices throw the MIDI data into the same callback function (the one that is assigned last).
I'd expected the callback function to be object specific rather than class specific. After a lot of research and tinkering i suspect the problem to be related to the fact that the callback function is declared static (as suggested by the RtMidi documentation) and thus declared class wide instead of object wide.

How do i fix the code, so that the MIDI events generated by the launchpads are sent to their 'own' callback function?

Here's the (condensed) code:

#### launchpad.cpp

```
class launchpad {
public:
    launchpad(int paramPortId, std::string paramPosition);
private:
    static void listenerCallback(double deltatime, std::vector< unsigned char > *message, void *userData);
    static std::string position;
};

std::string launchpad::position;

void launchpad::listenerCallback(double deltatime, std::vector< unsigned char > *message, void *userData) {
    unsigned int nBytes = message->size();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nBytes; i++)
        std::cout << position << "Byte " << i << " = " << (int) message->at(i) << ", ";
    if (nBytes > 0)
        std::cout << "stamp = " << deltatime << std::endl;
}

launchpad::launchpad(int paramPortId, std::string paramPosition) {

    RtMidiIn *input = new RtMidiIn();
    launchpad::position = paramPosition;
    std::cout << "Launchpad found at port # " << paramPortId << " assigned position: " << position << std::endl;

    input->setCallback(&listenerCallback);
    input->openPort(paramPortId);
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   RtMidiIn *infoDevice;
   launchpad *leftLaunchpad = 0;
   launchpad *rightLaunchpad = 0;
   int launchpadIndex = 0;
   infoDevice = new RtMidiIn();
   unsigned int nPorts = infoDevice->getPortCount();
   string portName;

   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nPorts; i++) {
       portName = infoDevice->getPortName(i);
       if (portName == "Launchpad") {
           if (launchpadIndex == 0) {
               leftLaunchpad = new launchpad(i, "left");
               launchpadIndex++;
           } else if (launchpadIndex == 1) {
               rightLaunchpad = new launchpad(i, "right");
               launchpadIndex++;
           }
       }
}

    char input;
    std::cin.get(input);
    return 0;
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

listenerCallback can be any static C function not from the class

then Use
input->setCallback(&listenerCallback,(void *)this);
and userdata will tell you what is being called

Comment: correct, but a terminological gripe ;) "not from the class" is very inaccurate as a `static` member method is definitely part of the `class`. That's why, as you pointed out, it can access instance members including `private` ones, as long as it is given a `this` pointer/reference to work with. It's part of the class, albeit not tied to a specific _instance_. A non-class function could only access public members/methods - probably not much use in reality.

Comment: setting the user callback providing the pointer to the userData (which can be a pointer to any appropriate user data structure) is very sparingly and ambiguously documented even in the original RtMidi documentation. Thanks